# how to change the theme color of vscode-edge-devtools?

Tags: visual-studio-code, devtools, screencast

I configured my **settings.json** with the following option

```json
"vscode-edge-devtools.themes": "Dark",
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image]